# Conflict dependency when installing groovy-eclipse plugin to Luna

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-luna, groovy-eclipse

I have a fresh downloaded copy of eclipse Luna (eclipse-java-luna-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz) (Version: Luan Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600) from official website.

When I am trying to install groovy-eclipse plugin(The only available version I have found are: Groovy-Eclipse for Juno 2.7.1 and Groovy-Eclipse for Indigo 2.7.1 both are released by VMware, inc., EPL), it does not matter which one I try, I always see the 'Groovy-Eclipse Feature' package will not be installed due to a conflict dependency:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>    Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e42-RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e42-RELEASE)
>     Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.4.2.20150219-0708 (epp.package.java 4.4.2.20150219-0708)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>       Java Development Tools Core 3.10.2.v20150120-1634 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.2.v20150120-1634)
>       Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.10.2.v_OTDT_r232_201502101148 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.2.v_OTDT_r232_201502101148)
>       Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.10.0.v_OTDT_r231_201409160728 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.0.v_OTDT_r231_201409160728)
>       Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.10.0.v_OTDT_r230_201406101339 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.0.v_OTDT_r230_201406101339)
>       Java Development Tools Core 3.10.0.v20140902-0626 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.0.v20140902-0626)
>       Java Development Tools Core 3.8.3.xx-201411061336-e42-RELEASE (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.3.xx-201411061336-e42-RELEASE)
>       Java Development Tools Core 3.10.0.v20140604-1726 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.0.v20140604-1726)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.4.2.20150219-0708 (epp.package.java 4.4.2.20150219-0708)
>       To: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group [4.4.2.20150219-0708]

It looks to me like the Luna build-in package 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.4.2.20150219-0708' has some sub-packages that conflict with 'Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e42-RELEASE' which is shipped by groovy-eclipse plugin.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason as shown on the error message is that some packages provided by old version of groovy-eclipse plugin conflict with those packages that shipped with later version of Eclipse (in this case Luna).

So the fix/ work around would be to install the groovy plugin that compatible with the later version of Eclipse.

Instead of installing groovy-eclipse 2.7.1, I need to install Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) for Eclipse 3.6.4.RELEASE (released by Pivotal, EPL). on the install page, just pick those sub-packages that suit your needs. In my case, I need:
1. Eclipse Quicksearch
2. Groovy compiler 2.0 Feature
3. Groovy-Eclipse Feature
4. JDT Core patch for Groovy-Eclipse plugin on Eclipse 4.4

This worked for me.